How to convert SVG image source to any IconSource in WinUI 3
I want to convert a SVG image to any kind of IconSource so I can use it in TabViewItem.IconSource
BitmapIconSource icon = new()
{
    UriSource = new Uri("http://url/image.svg"),//This doesn't work, BitmapIconSource cannot render svg
    ShowAsMonochrome = false,
};
TabViewItem.IconSource = icon;

SVGImageSource is not useable in IconSource. Am I able to convert SVG to IconSource or do I have to set it directly to the TabViewItem.Header like this?
SvgImageSource ImageSource = new() { UriSource = new Uri("http://url/image.svg") };
ImageIcon SVGIcon = new() { Source= ImageSource };
SVGIcon.Width = 15;
SVGIcon.Height = 15;
TabViewItem.Header = SVGIcon;


Have you tried using PathIconSource?  I know nothing about winui, but that type says its for vector paths and extends IconSource.

Does it work with a local svg file? Also make sure to use WinAppSDK v1.5.240607001 or later to avoid this issue.

I don't think PathIconSource  can read svg file because svg is a little bit like html and path icon uses command

I am using WinAppSDK 1.6. Bitmapicon doesn't work with any svg. But SVGImage source works on the same link

You may convert the SVG image to path data and use it with PathIcon?

According to @AndrewKeepCoding 's comment, I tested with a local svg file and it works. You can use them as local svg files.

I didn't find any ways to convert SVG to path data. And I tried local svg file on TabViewItem.IconSource = new BitmapIconSource(){ UriSource = new Uri("C://localpath/name.svg")} but it doesn't work.

You need to include the SVG image in your project and Set Build Action to Content. BitmapIconSource bitmapSource = new() {      UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/TestSVG.svg"),      ShowAsMonochrome = false, };

Using a BitmapIconSource with an SVG won't work. SVGs aren't bitmaps. Whether you add SVG files as Content files to your project makes no difference.

You would use an ImageIconSource (instead of a BitmapIconSource) with an SvgImageSource like this:
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
...

var icon = new ImageIconSource
{
    ImageSource = new SvgImageSource(new Uri("http://url/image.svg"))
};

tabViewItem.IconSource = icon;


Am I able to set ImageSource property to a SVGImageSource? Because the document of ImageIconSource said "ImageSource: the uri of the image file"

Why would you not simply try the code in the answer? It does of course work.

Lol, because I cannot use my laptop now, sorry
